# CodingKeys conformance generates a compiler error

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I have a struct `DynamicKey` which conforms to `CodingKey`..
Then I decided I will extend the already existing functionality of `KeyedEncodingContainer` with a function to encode `[String: Any]`..

So now I get to the conformance part in my `Struct Foo` but I get a compiler error..

Any ideas why the compiler says that `Foo.CodingKeys` does not conform to `CodingKeys` when it inherits from `DynamicKey` which has the conformance?

Not Working Code:

```
struct DynamicKey: CodingKey, Equatable, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int? { return nil }

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }

    //MARK:- Equatable Methods
    public static func == (lhs: DynamicKey, rhs: DynamicKey) -> Bool {
        return lhs.stringValue == rhs.stringValue
    }

    //MARK:- ExpressibleByStringLiteral Methods
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.stringValue = value
    }

    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }

    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(stringLiteral: value)
    }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainer where Key: CodingKey /*where Key == DynamicKey*/ {
    mutating func encodeDynamicValues(_ value: [String: Any], forKey key: Key) throws {
        //Other code here..
    }
}

struct Foo: Encodable {
    var arr: [String: Any]

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

        //Compiler Error: Instance method 'container(keyedBy:)' requires that 'Foo.CodingKeys' conform to 'CodingKey'
        //However, Foo.CodingKeys conforms to `CodingKey` because `DynamicKey` implements the protocol..
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)



        try container.encodeDynamicValues(arr, forKey: .arr)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: DynamicKey {
        case arr
    }
}
```

However, if I change `DynamicKey` to a class and then use the `&` operator to make the enum conform, the compiler error goes away (without the `&`, it will give the same error).. Why?

Working Code:

```
final class DynamicKey: CodingKey { //I don't need the equatable and expressible when it's a class so ignore that part.. adding it doesn't change anything..
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int? { return nil }

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainer where Key: CodingKey /*where Key == DynamicKey*/ {
    mutating func encodeDynamicValues(_ value: Any, forKey key: Key) throws {
        //Other Code Here..
    }
}

struct Foo: Encodable {
    var arr: [String: Any]

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        //CodingKeys now conforms to `CodingKey` because I made `DynamicKey` a class and used the `&` `CodingKey`
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encodeDynamicValues(arr, forKey: .arr)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: DynamicKey & CodingKey {
        case arr
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your first example

The problem in the first example is simply a matter of your understanding of this line:

```
enum CodingKeys: DynamicKey
```

You say:

> Any ideas why the compiler says that Foo.CodingKeys does not conform to CodingKeys when it inherits from DynamicKey which has the conformance?

But Foo.CodingKeys does *not* “inherit from DynamicKey”. Nothing can “inherit” from a struct. The notation here has nothing to do with inheritance. What you have made is an enum with a raw value of type DynamicKey. (Normally you wouldn’t be able to do that — a raw value type needs to be “expressible by a string, integer, or floating-point literal" but you got around that by making DynamicKey Equatable and ExpressibleByStringLiteral.)

It’s the same syntax as if you had said:

```
enum MyEnum : Int {
    case myCase // zero
}
```

(You have also confused yourself by using the magic name CodingKeys for your enum. But that’s probably not directly germane.)

---

#### Your second example

Then in your second example, where DynamicKey is a class, you are confused in exactly the opposite way. Here, you’ve done something totally different:

```
enum CodingKeys: DynamicKey & CodingKey {
```

Here, your enum does *not* have any raw value type; the stuff after the colon declares a protocol restriction. But here you’ve fooled yourself in yet another way, because in fact the DynamicKey part is irrelevant; the code would compile just as well if you simply said

```
enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
```

All that’s really happening in that example is that you’ve asked for autosynthesis of conformance to CodingKey, and you’ve gotten it.

Comment: I don't understand.. Why would `enum CodingKeys: DynamicKey, CodingKey` not work then? Similarly if I did `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey` it works just fine..

Comment: No, why would it? If MyEnum has a raw value type of Int, MyEnum is not therefore magically a Numeric.

Comment: Then how come it works when I use `String` instead of `DynamicKey`? Both of them are `RawRepresentable`

Comment: Because the magic behind-the-scenes code expects exactly that: an enum with a String raw value named CodingKeys that is marked as conforming to CodingKey. Strings are what keys _are_. So the behind the scenes code can autogenerate implementations for the CodingKeys requirements. It can’t do that with a raw value of DynamicKey.

Comment: If it can't do that when my rawValue is `DynamicKey` then why would it work when it's a class and not a struct.. It seems to work just fine so long as I tell it that it also conforms to `CodingKey`.. and it only works if I use ampersand not comma..

Comment: Okay, so that’s a _different_ misunderstanding of what your own words mean. `enum CodingKeys: DynamicKey & CodingKey` has no raw value specification.

Comment: And the DynamicKey part is actually irrelevant anyway in the second example.

Comment: Hmm so it's legit impossible to make my own `CodingKey` that the enum can conform. :( Must be string or int I guess..

Comment: The fact that you are even allowed to say `enum CodingKeys: DynamicKey & CodingKey` (where DynamicKey is a class) seems to me to be a bug, and I will proceed to report it as such.